# Smtp server which expect SSL connection on 465 or 587

Tags: vb.net, smtp, tcpclient

There are SMTP servers that use port 465 for a secure connection, however , when a use a TcpClient to connect to these servers on this port, no greeting message is sent, have i to secure the connection immediately after the connection ??

Answer (score 1):

465 is meant for STMP over SSL, you'll have to establish an SSL connection **before** the SMTP conversation even starts, otherwise you won't get anything back, including a greeting banner. TLS works differently by starting a conversation and then encrypting.

Comment: i tried and found that , no greeting is given, and the connection is meant to be followed immediately by a security negotiation with no STARTTLS command . i just tried it with smtp.gmail.com on port 465 , i connect the client and secured the connection with an SslStream and then i received a greeting message..i am now testing for tls.